# SQL group by item and group by month

Tags: sql, database

I am using SQL Developer to query a database view. The view consist of the following columns: [DeviceName, DateOfCalculation, Value_of_Watt]

We have our devices set up in multiple houses to calculate their electricity Watt in a daily basis.
So each deviceName is repeated multiple times in the view for each day it calculates.

I want to query this view by summing up the value of Watt of each month for each device. So each device's name is only repeated per month.year and not day.month.year.

As an example, this is our view now:

| deviceName | date | wattValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| device1 | 1-may-21 | 60 |
| device1 | 2-may-21 | 40 |
| device1 | 3-may-21 | 45 |
| ....... | ........ | .. |
| device1 | 1-jun-21 | 45 |
| ....... | ........ | .. |
| device2 | 1-may-21 | 55 |
| device2 | 2-may-21 | 57 |
| device2 | 3-may-21 | 50 |
| ....... | ........ | .. |
| device2 | 1-jun-21 | 45 |
| ....... | ........ | .. |

What we want is to sum up the Watt Value for each month for each device instead of each day, here the WattValue is summed up for that particular month:

| deviceName | date | wattValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| device1 | 1-may-21 | 145 |
| device1 | 1-Jun-21 | 100 |
| ....... | ........ | .. |
| ....... | ........ | .. |
| device2 | 1-may-21 | 162 |
| device2 | 1-Jun-21 | 190 |
| ....... | ........ | .. |

Note: The calculaions are continous for years and years. The calculations in this question are random for the sake of the question.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT deviceName, MONTH(date),YEAR(date), Sum(WattValue)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY deviceName, MONTH(date),YEAR(date)
```

Comment: @RawanAlMaawali . . . SQL Developer is used (almost exclusively) for Oracle and this code does not work in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer is associated with Oracle.  In Oracle, I would truncate the date:

```
select deviceName, trunc(date, 'MON') as yyyymm, sum(wattvalue)
from t
group by deviceName, trunc(date, 'MON')
order by yyyymm;
```